# not able to configure exchange mail in evolution

Tags: evolution, evolution-mapi

Recently I am start using ubuntu 14.04 LTS. for my corporate exchange mail, I found evolution mail client with mapi plugin. while configuring everything goes fine (i.e. password authentication successfully completed) and finished. but my account not shown in the mail client. I tried lot of times, but no response. please suggest me in this issue.

Ubuntu version - 14.04 LTS
evolution version - 3.10.04

Answer (score 0):

You can use Davmail - it's Exchange <--> IMAP/Carddav/Caldav connector. Then connect using any IMAP compatible email client, for example, Thunderbird.
See more: http://davmail.sourceforge.net/